# NSPageController, If selectedIndex is used at animator(), autoresizingMask has no effect

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

If selectedIndex is used at animator(), autoresizingMask has no effect.
If you don't use animator(), you were fine.
It is not possible to do selectedIndex manually with animator().

Please tell me if you know.

- self.animator().selectedIndex = 2

[image]
[image]

- self.selectedIndex = 2

[image]

source

```
let array = ["page 1", "page 2", "page 3", "page 4", "page 5", "page 6"]

class PageController: NSPageController, NSPageControllerDelegate {

    @IBAction func moveThreePage(_ sender: Any) {
        // NG
        self.animator().selectedIndex = 2

        // OK
        //self.selectedIndex = 2
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
        self.arrangedObjects = array
    }

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, viewControllerForIdentifier identifier: String) -> NSViewController {
        let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateController(withIdentifier: "ViewController") as! ViewController
        vc.view.autoresizingMask = [.height, .width]
        return vc
    }

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, identifierFor object: Any) -> String {
        return "ViewController"
    }

    func pageController(_ pageController: NSPageController, prepare viewController: NSViewController, with object: Any?) {
        guard let item = object as? String,
              let itemVC = viewController as? ViewController else {
            return
        }

        itemVC.item = item
    }

    func pageControllerDidEndLiveTransition(_ pageController: NSPageController) {
        self.completeTransition()
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try what's in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspagecontroller?language=objc)? "Programatic animations via the animator proxy do not call the delegate methods and you are responsible for calling completeTransition when the animation completes.This is easily done via a completion handler on an NSAnimationContext grouping."

Comment: Thanks, Willeke. I tried the contents of the document that taught me.
It was fine. I was looking at this [document](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspagecontroller/1434988-selectedindex). It was "use the animator object of NSPageController class". This was an ambiguous statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you. it is complete.

```
@IBAction func moveThreePage(_ sender: Any) {
    //To animate a selectedIndex change:
    NSAnimationContext.runAnimationGroup({ context in
        self.animator().selectedIndex = 2
    }, completionHandler: {
        self.completeTransition()
    })
}
```